# Swift: functions run several times per load viewcontroller

Tags: swift, quickblox

I use below code in `viewController.swift`

```
func didReceiveNewSession(_ session: QBRTCSession, userInfo: [String : String]? = nil) {
    print("PLAY SESSION")
}
```

I open application and after receive session i get one log `PLAY SESSION`

But if i open application and i go to `viewControllerPage.swift` and back again to `viewController.swift` and after that receive session i get two log `PLAY SESSION`

As the result, if i open `viewController.swift` 7-8 times, after receive session print 7-8 `PLAY SESSION`

I want only get once session even i open every time `viewController.swift`

I want `didReceiveNewSession` load once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is exactly what viewDidload and viewDidAppear are for

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //insert the code you only want to run once here
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    //insert the code you want to run every time you load the VC
}
```

was there a particular reason why you did not want to use them?  alternatively you could use viewWillAppear() instead of viewDidAppear()